# Fatal error: Index out of range when delete cell from tableview rxswift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have simple tableview. . When I want to delete cell from table view, I get that error.

**View controller code**:

```
class FoodCategoryDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var foodCategoryDetailViewModel: FoodCategoryDetailTableViewViewModelType?

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let foodCategoryDetailViewModel = foodCategoryDetailViewModel else { return }

        tableView.delegate = nil
        tableView.dataSource = nil

        foodCategoryDetailViewModel.foodsInSelectedCategory
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: FoodCategoryDetailTableViewCell.cellIdentifier, cellType: FoodCategoryDetailTableViewCell.self))
            { row, food, cell in
                cell.foodCategoryDetailCellViewModel = foodCategoryDetailViewModel.cellViewModel(forRow: row)
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        tableView.rx.itemDeleted.subscribe({ [unowned self] indexPath in
            self.foodCategoryDetailViewModel?.removeFoodFromApplication(atRow: (indexPath.element?.row)!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

**View Model code**:

```
class FoodCategoryDetailTableViewViewModel: FoodCategoryDetailTableViewViewModelType {
    var foodsInSelectedCategory: BehaviorRelay<[Food]>
    private var foodCategoryId: Int16

    func cellViewModel(forRow row: Int) -> FoodTableViewCellViewModelType? {
        if let food = getFood(atRow: row) {
            return FoodTableViewCellViewModel(foodModel: food)
        }
        return nil
    }

    func removeFoodFromApplication(atRow row: Int) {
        if let food = getFood(atRow: row) {
            var foods = foodsInSelectedCategory.value
            foods.remove(at: row)
            self.foodsInSelectedCategory = BehaviorRelay(value: foods)
            CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.removeFoodFromApplication(foodName: food.name!)
        }
    }

    private func getFood(atRow row: Int) -> Food? {
        let food = foodsInSelectedCategory.value[row]

        return food
    }

    init(foodCategoryId: Int16) {
        self.foodCategoryId = foodCategoryId
        self.foodsInSelectedCategory = BehaviorRelay(value: CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.fetchFoodsFromSelectedCategory(foodCategoryId: self.foodCategoryId))
    }
}
```

I am using Core Data. I get error in function `getFood()`. It error exist because `row` in view controller have old count of items in tableview. It is not updating with new count of items (foods) after delete cell.

Comment: Use numberOfRowsInSection = foods.count after all... or better put a tag on your cells, where tag = index of foodsInSelectedCategory ..this way even if you delete a row, the index shall stay there as reference

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection is not working =(

Comment: are u using RxDataSource? than `self.tableView.reloadData()` isn't it redundant ?? once u call `self.foodCategoryDetailViewModel?.removeFoodFromApplication(atRow: (indexPath.element?.row)!)` table should be reloaded automotically

Comment: no, I am not use RxDataSource

Comment: @tkas: You are setting `tableView.dataSource = nil` how do you expect number of sections and number of rows to get called if u r not using RxDataSource???

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari thx for your answer, I will try use RxDataSource

Comment: @Tkas: I don't think RxDataSource will help you. I think you have multiple problems here but the sample code doesn't compile so I can't tell for sure. On problem you _absolutely_ have is this line `self.foodsInSelectedCategory = BehaviorRelay(value: CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.fetchFoodsFromSelectedCategory(foodCategoryId: self.foodCategoryId))`. You should _never_ replace a BehaviorRelay. It will break all of your existing subscriptions.

Comment: @Daniel T. thank you! How to update my BehaviorRelay (foodsInSelectedCategory) without replacing?

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452582/how-to-use-behaviorrelay-as-an-alternate-to-variable-in-rxswift) of Ashkan Sarlak helped me. But deleting without animation...

Comment: @Tkas: `.accept()` is the correct way as I recall.

Comment: @Daniel T. I wrote extension with remove function: `public extension BehaviorRelay where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    public func remove(at index: Element.Index) {
        var newValue = value
        newValue.remove(at: index)
        accept(newValue)
    }
}`